# IntelliJ Android plugin: suppress generation of BuildConfig.java or change where it is written?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am trying to stop IntelliJ from putting generated files in my primary source folder. These generated .java files are interfering with glob rules that I use with other tools. (Think `find -name '*.java'`.)

For Android development, I appear to be able to customize the output directory for `R.java` and files generated from the AIDL compiler, but IntelliJ appears insistent on creating a `gen/` directory and writing a `BuildConfig.java` file in my source tree. Is there anything that I can do to stop it?

I realize that normally, the `gen/` folder is created alongside the `src/` folder, but in my case, I am using something like:

```
<sourceFolder packagePrefix="com.example" />
```

so the `gen/` directory that is created under `com.example` and looks like a new package (`com.example.gen`) whereas it is not.

Comment: I can only suggest you to not use package prefix and change the layout of your folders. It doesn't play well with Android.

Comment: I think IntelliJ should give us the option not to genrate BuildConfig.java files. I use maven and it also generates those files. Now I have to manually disable compilation of the BuidlConfig in the gen/ folder.

Comment: Try using a gradle build instead. it will be the new standard and Android studio is based on IntelliJ already.

Answer (score 1):

click File->Project Structure->Facets,you can here found your android app,click **Generated sources** here, now you can set **Directory for generated files** here。